# An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Warning: Loss of data on string conversion")

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, twig

I'm using http://php-decimal.io/

Here is my twig

```
<td class="text-right">{{ accDocument.taxValueSum|number_format(3, ',', ' ') }} {{ accDocument.currency.code }}</td>
```

and Here is my function in entity

```
public function getVatValue(): Decimal     
{         
    return new Decimal($this->vatValue, 3);     
}
```

Comment: And which is the issue? You don't know how to treat that exception? Or you don't know what's the meaning of the exception?

Comment: I don't know how to treat that exception.

Comment: Obviously you should catch it ([try/catch](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php)) and, depending on your business case, do something with it. Or simply ignore it if you are sure that the string is a decimal.

Comment: @AdiFatol There is no try/catch inside `twig`

Comment: You can catch it where is thrown, which I suppose it happens in the getter, getVatValue()

Comment: Mostly in the filter `number_format`

Comment: @AdiFatol how to ignore it?

Comment: @DarkBee The error is definitely thrown in the [Decimal class](http://php-decimal.io/#basic-usage) constructor.

@Animal `try { new Decimal(...) } catch (...) { /* do nothing here */ }`

Comment: I wonder how your `getVatValue()` is being called, when you access `accDocument.taxValueSum`... the sum surely is something different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked with increasing precision from 3 to 15.

```
public function getVatValue(): Decimal     
{         
    return new Decimal($this->vatValue, 15);     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [official doc](http://php-decimal.io/#basic-usage):

> A warning will be raised if value was not parsed completely. For
> example, "0.135" to a precision of 2 will result in "0.14" with a
> warning. Similarly, 123 with a precision of 2 would result in 120 with
> a warning because data has been lost.

As my understanding, precision is related to the value length. So `new Decimal($value, strlen((string) $value))` should work. In your case:

```
public function getVatValue(): Decimal     
{         
    return new Decimal($this->vatValue, strlen((string) $this->vatValue));     
}
```